# Partial View with empty page ASP MVC 3

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

I am developing an ASP.Net MVC 3 application using C# and SQL Server 2005. I am using Entity Framework with a code-first approach.

I have an interface for the LOG ON (connection) which is related to my base where I have a USER table (contain Login + password).

This is the View of connexion :LogonPartial.acx (partial view that strongly typed from the UserViewModel)

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MvcApplication2.ViewModels.UserViewModel>" %>


<%
    if (Request.IsAuthenticated) {
%>

        Welcome <strong><%: Page.User.Identity.Name %></strong>!
        [ <%: Html.ActionLink("Log Off", "LogOff", "Account") %> ]
<%
    }
    else {
%> 
        [ <%: Html.ActionLink("Log On", "LogOn", "Account") %> ]
<%
    }
%>
```

When the connexion success : I have only the 'Log On' link.
When the connexion fails : the page is empty

This is the Controller :

```
[ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult LogedInUser()
        {
            var user = new UserViewModel();
            if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                user.Nom_User = User.Identity.Name;
            }
            return PartialView(user);
        }
private GammeContext db = new GammeContext();
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1054:UriParametersShouldNotBeStrings",
            Justification = "Needs to take same parameter type as Controller.Redirect()")]
        public ActionResult LogedInUser(string Matricule, string passWord, bool rememberMe, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (!ValidateLogOn(Matricule, passWord))
            {
                return Connection(Matricule, passWord, returnUrl);
            }

            //FormsAuth.SignIn(Matricule, rememberMe);

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }

        public ActionResult Connection(string Matricule, string passWord, string returnUrl)
        {
            List<User> users = db.Users.ToList();
            ActionResult output = null;

            if (users.Any())
            {
                foreach (User u in users)
                {
                    if ((u.Matricule == Matricule) && (u.passWord == passWord))
                    {
                        output = View();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                output = Redirect(returnUrl);
            }

            return output;
        }
```

Comment: Well first of you're never even using your UserViewModel. Second of all I'm not sure what you mean by "connection success" (I presume, login succeeded), but if this is the case you're not authenticating your users correct.

Comment: Yes, Login successeded this what i mean. I think that the authentification is alright because when I put the values which exist in the base, it 's take me to a page with LogOn link. However, in the opposite case, it s take me to an empty page

Comment: This logic should be in your controller not your page.  What does the code look like in your Account controller?

Comment: @KOL Please take a look at the EDIT

Comment: I dont see your LogOn Method or your LogOff method that your action links are calling in the code you have added

Comment: Oh you are right,,,because the original name of LogedInUser is LogOn but when I create the partial view LogedInUser,,,I change all of this !!! I try now to change the name of methode in the partial view to 'LogedInUser' but nothing as result !

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where you're authenticating the user ? What if you try this:

```
if (!ValidateLogOn(Matricule, passWord))
{       
   return Connection(Matricule, passWord, returnUrl);
}

// user is valid, authenticate
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(Matricule, true);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the 'password' is not accepeted (does not exist in the current context),,,,I try it with 'passWord',,,all the statement bacame in Red (overloaded Method)

Comment: Oops sorry, the second parameter is a Boolean (persistence), check out my edit

Comment: Oh no problem, I correct and I try it but the result is the same !
Sorry,,but can you take a look at my conversation Above,,,I think the probem is there !

Answer (score 1):

Your ActionLink needs to be updated correctly.

It should take the format in your example above of:

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Text on UI", "MethodNameInController", "ControllerName") %>
```

You have not done that above - you have action links that don't have methods in the controller.  I would also recommend you go through this tutorial -

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-3

Comment: Thanks !I read this tuto before (this is not the first time that someone suggest me this tuto),,,I am beginner ,,I know what I should put in ActionLink ! the first mistake because I forget to change it ! Please,,,I don't think the problem is there ,,,because also the name of logged user doesn't appear !!